# Classification of tiles that admit no aperiodic tiling

Tags: group-theory, euclidean-geometry, tiling

Are the convex mono-tiles that only admit periodic edge-to-edge tilings classified? If so, can you give a reference?

I tried to find answers to this question and related information on the web, but was not successful. I am aware that for some tiles (such as rectangles) it is easy to construct non-periodic tilings, but could not find any information concerning the opposite. It could be that the question is too simple to be interesting or at the other extreme unsolved (the latter seems very unlikely, as my searches have come up empty).

Comment: There is a massive amount of literature on this topic. I randomly selected an [article](https://eprints.gla.ac.uk/252869/2/252869.pdf) on this topic, which contains many references. Note Gr ̈unbaum and Shephard's book and Penrose's work.

Comment: Many thanks. I will check Grünbaum & Shepard's book. While the article you linked looks very interesting, it is concerned with the much-studied question of finding tiles that have no periodic tilings (aperiodic ones). My question is about which convex tiles that do tile periodically, only tile periodically edge-to-edge which is the other extreme, that seems not to have attracted attention.

In the references I noticed "Topology of Tiling Spaces". I had a look at the table of contents. This looked interesting, but it also seems doubtful that this text deals with my question. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I would be shocked if such tiles have been classified. My guess is that one can probably find a construction with Wang tiles or similar which embeds some NP-complete problem in the question of whether a tile admits nonperiodic tilings or only periodic ones; it's not the sort of thing that seems like it has any reason to be simple, and so by default I expect it to be terrifyingly difficult, since this is the default for tiling classifications.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect: That is exactly my suspicion for the framework you mention (including Wang tiles). I have some hope for the case of convex tiles and I would actually be happy with only deciding one particular case: That of the versatile pentagon by Marjorie Rice which seems to have a lot of different periodic tesselations. A few are listed here: [link](https://www.gathering4gardner.org/g4g13gift/puzzles/SchattschneiderDoris-GiftExchange-MarjorieRiceVersatile-G4G13.pdf) and there exist others. Is it possible to list all possiblilities? Does it have any non-periodic edge-to-edge tiling?

Comment: Whoops, I missed "convex" in your question - sorry about that! For the linked pentagon, consider the tiling on the second page, extended to cover the plane; these tiles are separated into infinite strips by horizontal lines, and we can reflect one of these strips to point the other way while maintaining edge-to-edge connections. This results in a tiling that's singly periodic, but not doubly periodic.

Comment: Thanks @RavenclawPrefect. Your refer to the first patch on page 2 — I feel stupid to have missed that construction of a non-periodic example. I also realise that I formulated my initial question poorly

I was aiming for "Will it always be possible to list all periodic edge-to-edge tilings for a given convex tile" and thought we will either have a good procedure if we can't have an non-periodic tiling or we will not be sure (for the versatile pentagon) that we know all solutions otherwise. I should have asked straight for "will there always be  a procedure to find all periodic solutions".

Comment: … want to add: I was wondering initially about how unusual the tiling at the entry of the MAA-building (see [link](http://mathtourist.blogspot.com/2010/06/tiling-with-pentagons.html)) is. It seems to use the patch in the lower left corner of page two of [link](https://www.gathering4gardner.org/g4g13gift/puzzles/SchattschneiderDoris-GiftExchange-MarjorieRiceVersatile-G4G13.pdf). The tiling would look less unusual if it was larger. Would we always be (somewhat) disappointed if we viewed arbitrary large parts of a tiling by discovering the periodicity? My Mathematical framing of this was not good

Comment: … and now that we have your non-periodic example, it seems possible that if given a finite portion of the tiling we will never know if this should be a periodic or a non-periodic tiling (not yet entirely sure). This makes me feel aesthetic confusion ‍.

Comment: It's always possible to list all periodic edge-to-edge tilings for a given convex tile, in the sense that there's a program that, for any polygonal tile, will print out every periodic tiling using copies of that tile: just try all possible finite patches in order, and print them out when they tile translationally. However, you're not in general guaranteed that there will be a program that can figure out what the final output of that list looks like (e.g. its length) in finite time.